# ¿Es correcto decir "El (infinitivo del verbo) ...."?

Tags: gramática

Encontre el siguiente [artículo](http://elregio.com/archives/42652) y la siguiente frase dicha por un pólitico de aquí de Monterrey:

> **“El eliminar** al 100 por ciento la tenencia nos va a afectar en todas
>   estas áreas de inversión; yo creo que está bien invertido el dinero y
>   está aplicado en la prioridad que está pidiendo la población… Si
>   ahorita ustedes le preguntan a la gente van a decir, queremos
>   seguridad, bueno, vamos a dejar de invertir en seguridad yo creo que
>   sería irresponsable”.

La pregunta es: ¿Es correcto decir "El eliminar ..." que no debería ser solamente "Eliminar ...."?. En otras palabras, ¿es correcto decir "El (**infinitivo del verbo**) ...."?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El uso de artículo con un infinitivo nominal es de por sí correcto, como señala, por ejemplo, la [Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consultas-A-articulo-infinitivo-2540.html). Esto es porque el infinitivo nominal cumple la función de nombre y puede recibir los mismos modificadores.

Ahora, hay verbos (como “eliminar”) que directamente suenan mal en función nominal, y más si llevan artículo. A veces es porque resulta una cacofonía (“el-el”), otras porque se usa más el sustantivo derivado (“la eliminación”), etc... pero no hay una razón estrictamente gramatical para decir que sea incorrecto el uso del artículo.

Comment: No estamos aquí en presencia de un infinito nominal, es este un claro ejemplo de infinitivo fático o infinitivo introductorio.

Comment: Como respuesta, decirte que esta oración tiene un infinitivo introductorio, pero el de la pregunta es nominal. El infinitivo introductorio se reconoce porque se le puede poner delante “hay que”, “quiero”, etc. Obviamente no pueden llevar artículo.

Comment: Se trata de un infinitivo introductorio convertido artificialmente en infinitivo nominal. El sujeto de la oración es la eliminación de la tenencia, eliminar. http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Al%20ante%20infinitivo.htm

Comment: Sí, cuando el infinitivo ejerce la función de sustantivo y es sujeto de la oración, se llama “infinitivo nominal”.